# Why my baking on a plane is broken?

Tags: baking

I'm trying to bake some foliage on a plane, but i can't find out why some part of my mesh is not baked. I tried to move in substance to see if it would work but it does something similar. Does someone know where the problem could come from?
Thanks
[image]

edit :
I recalculated the normal, which removed the green errors, but it was still missing some parts. I decided to add some subdivisions to get some extra details, and worked fine right after that.
[image]

Comment: Maybe recalculate the normals? If not, could you please share your file?

Comment: Thank you, recalculating the normal did some improvement showed in the picture, but some parts were still missing, then i decide to add some subdivision to get more details and it worked.